# get rows index when checking rows of bootstrap table jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Hello I'm trying to get rows index when I check a specific row in my bootstrapTable.
I tried to do that with the event 'check.bs.table' but it doesn't really return something related to the index!

```
$('#gridModalListeDossiers').on('check.bs.table', lang.hitch( this, function (row , $element) {
            console.log("row", row)
            console.log("elemnt :", $element)
        }))
```

Is there any other way to get rows index when checking specific rows?

Update : thnks for your help but I just discovered another way to do it (first I get the data of my table then I get the index of the selected data) :

```
$('#gridModalListeDossiers').on('check.bs.table', lang.hitch( this, function (row , $element) {
            var dataTable = $('#gridModalListeDossiers').bootstrapTable('getData')
            $.each(dataTable, function (i, rowData) {
                if (rowData.select_dossier === true) {
                    $('#gridDossiers').bootstrapTable('check', i)
                }
            })
        }))
```

Comment: In `datatable` or plain html table?

Comment: plain html table

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that prints the position of a table cell when you change the value of the checkbox it contains:

```
$("#my-table input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    console.log("row's position = " + $(this).parents('tr').index());
    console.log("cell's position = " + $(this).parents('td').index());
});
```

Comment: In my table I have a checkbox, that's why I used the event 'check.bs.table' and it fires when I check a specific row. Any idea how to adapt that to a checkbox?

Comment: I have edited my answer considering a table with cells containing a checkbox.